# copying csv file from gmail atthacment to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I receive a daily csv report by gmail and I want to automaticaly copy the date in the csv to a google sheet. This sheet is in turn used as a data soure for a datastudio report.

I've tried multiple scripts and non seem to work. This code here is the closest I've come to my goal. Apps script runs without error. But, on the sheet I only get the time at which the script ran. No data from the csv.

```
 function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:CAQ Crea");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages().pop();

  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  if (attachment != null) {
    var attachName = attachment.getName();

    // Is the attachment a CSV file
    if (attachName.substring(attachName.length-4) === ".csv") {
      var id = "1UdbfOL7nMFJqkuNBt0YFKrNMLTs5pMpIithBoJ5_VkQ";
      var name = "CAQ Beeswax - DATA";
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
      var tab = sheet.getSheetByName(name);
      var tabInfo = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
      tabInfo.getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());

    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy csv attachment in Spreadsheet

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:CAQ Crea");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages().pop();
  var a = message.getAttachments()[0];
  if (a != null) {
    var aname = a.getName();
    if (aname.slice(-4) == ".csv") {
      var name = "CAQ Beeswax - DATA";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UdbfOL7nMFJqkuNBt0YFKrNMLTs5pMpIithBoJ5_VkQ");
      var tab = ss.getSheetByName(name);
      ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());//?
      var arr = Utilities.parseCsv(a.copyBlob().getDataAsString());
      tab.getRange(1,1,arr.length,arr[0].length);//not sure about the origin.  If you wish to append the perhaps tab.getLastRow() + 1 should be starting row
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: I should have also said that I want to date to ovewrite what was already there.